# Add icons to QuickPick List

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently writing an extension that lists files in a QuickPick dialogue. Is there a way to add the icons to the `QuickPickItem`'s label?

Or in other words, re-use the `vscode-icons` extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot reference an svg from something like the `vscode-icons` extension.

You *can* use [Github Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/) in any of the [QuickPickItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#QuickPickItem) properties right out of the box:

```
const items: vscode.QuickPickItem[] = [{label: '$(git-merge) Merge Branch',
                                        description: '$(git-commit) 1 commit',
                                        detail: '$(diff-added) 3 $(diff-modified) 2'}]
vscode.window.showQuickPick(items)
```

You can even just pass in an array of strings to `showQuickPick`:

`vscode.window.showQuickPick(['$(diff-added) Add', '$(diff-removed) Remove'])`

Comment: That's neat! Though the code for the icons is being displayed, when the filter matches its string. So litreally '$(diff-added) is being shown. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @NilsRiedemann you can make use of utf8 "icons" if possible, such as in the excellent [Gitlens](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/master/src/constants.ts#L92) extension. Otherwise, yes it is annoying that the ocitcons can be exposed by the filter.

Answer (score 0):

With vscode v1.81 there is a new api to use icons from anywhere, see [release notes: icons in quickPickItems](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_81.md#icons-in-quickpickitem-finalized).  Using this code:

```js
const qpOptions = { title: "demos of iconPaths", canPickMany: false };

const qpItems = [
  { label: "first item", iconPath: "C:\\Users\\Mark\\folder-operations\\images\\circle.svg" },
  { label: "second item", iconPath: "C:\\Users\\Mark\\folder-operations\\images\\image.png" },
  { label: "third item", iconPath: "C:\\Users\\Mark\\folder-operations\\images\\camera.svg" },
  { label: "fourth item", iconPath: "C:\\Users\\Mark\\\folder-operations\\images\\github.svg" },
  { label: "fifth item", iconPath: "C:\\Users\\Mark\\folder-operations\\images\\mail.svg" }
];

const selectedItem = await vscode.window.showQuickPick(qpItems, qpOptions);
```

Note the new `iconPath` property of a `QuickPickItem`.  I used various icons/svgs from different places and even a `png` (which worked but of course it is tiny).  For some reason I had to use an absolute path for the `iconPaths`.

[image: quickPickItems with iconPath]